# Problem with converting .py to .exe, "Fatal error: cant run the script"

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller

I am new to Python and a few months ago I started creating a program with databases and graphs from matplotlib.
I wanted to create an executable (.exe) with pyinstaller, all good, but then when I try to run it I get a popup saying "Fatal error: unable to run scrip". Try several ways but nothing.
This is the command I use on the cmd:

```
>pyinstaller --icon=./icon.ico MyApp.pyw
```

Also in the cmd it appears that there are libraries that were not found, but I do not use those libraries.
These are the libraries that I use is my program

```
tkinter, matplotlib, numpy, sqlite3, time
```

Please if someone can tell me what is happening or what I am doing wrong.
I do not put my code because it is quite long, but to get an idea it consists of entering data and graphing it.
Thanks :)

Comment: If you get "ModuleNotFoundError", try running the same command adding `--hidden-import "missing_module"`. You say that "there are libraries that were not found", could you post the logs? You may not use them directly, but some modules you imported can use them

Comment: Fix tags. Question has nothing to do with cmd.exe. Read tag info before adding them.